# Trying to connect to a SSH Server on WSL in the same network but the SSH connection is timing out

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So I am trying to configure my Ubuntu 22 laptop to connect with my Windows 11 machine running WSL. It worked perfectly yesterday and I could visualize everything I wanted. But now I cannot connect. This is what `ssh -vvv username@ip_address -p 2222` gives me on the client:

```
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.6, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/dummy.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/dummy.conf
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname [[ip_address]] is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/marlen/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/marlen/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to [[ip_address]] [[[ip_address]]] port 2222.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: connect to address [[ip_address]] port 2222: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host [[ip_address]] port 2222: Connection timed out
```

I configured a redirect as seen here in my Windows system:

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenaddress=[[ip_address]] listenport=2222 connectaddress=[[internal_ip_address]] connectport=22
```

Hence I'm trying to get into the port 22. Also, I added a rule for my firewall as follows:

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name=WSL2 dir=in action=allow protocol=TCP localport=2222
```

As I have been trying to recreate my process from yesterday there are multiple WSL2 rules. I was wondering if that could be a cause.

This is extra info from my WSL2:

```
sudo service ssh status
● ssh.service - OpenBSD Secure Shell server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ssh.service; enabled; ven>
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2024-03-28 11:57:10 -05; 2>

======

sudo netstat -paunt | egrep sshd\|:22
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      51694/sshd: /usr/sb
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      51694/sshd: /usr/sb
```

It seems everything is ok regarding ip:

On Windows:

```
Wireless LAN Wi-Fi 2:
IPv4. . . . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.149
```

On WSL

```
$ ip addr | grep eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 172.21.135.113/20 brd 172.21.143.255 scope global eth0
```

This is all the info I have. Thanks for any help you could provide me with.